# interact (with/on) each other difference

Tags: prepositions

> Then, when we decide something and act, how do rationale and emotion interact **with/on** each other?

Which is better and why?

Comment: Normally you'd use *interact with* and *act on*.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know, use of prepositions is often arbitrary and idiomatic.  One *interacts with* something but *acts on* or *upon* something.  There's some rationale to this, since interacting goes both ways and acting doesn't.

However, you may find something like this:

> They will interact on this matter tomorrow.

This is not an exception to the rule, because this is implied here:

> They will interact with one another on this matter tomorrow.